# JavaScript arr.every() method?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I was looking into Javascript `.every` documentation and it have a second parameter which is passed the description says

> Optional. Value to use as this when executing the callback. If a thisArg parameter is provided to every, it will be used as callback's this value. Otherwise, the value undefined will be used as its this value.  The this value ultimately observable by the callback is determined according to the usual rules for determining the this seen by a function.

which means that I can access that values as `this` in the callback function, what is a practical example of this?

Answer (score 4):

As per MDN,

> Optional. Value to use as `this` when executing `callback`. [[Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)]

It means, you can use provided value as `this` in callback function to test the value.

```js
const data = [0, 1, 2, 3];
const doesPass = data.every(function(el) {
  return el < this.toTest;
}, {
  toTest: 4
});
console.log(doesPass);
```

Comment: thanks. So if I want to test the Array with respect to another object or array then I can pass it as the second parameter and it can function also.

Comment: @dhunmoon None of the "practicle" examples show you need to use `this` and provide an impure function to the Array.prototype function(s) every or filter. Since you pass an object to `every` the object you want to use for `this` is already in scope and can be used by the function like so: `const o = {toTest:4};data.every(x=>x<o.toTest)` If the function passed is not defined as the same block as the object then you can define the function to take the object as parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Every iteration method of `Array` contains `thisArg` as second parameter. This is an example for filtering object keys with another object by using a prototype, which usually requires an object, which is handed over as argument, or in the second a bound to the method.

```js
var firstObject = { x: 0, y: 1, z: 2, a: 10, b: 20, e: 30 },
    secondObject = { x: 0, y: 1, z: 2, a: 10, c: 20, d: 30 };

function intersection(o1, o2) {
    return Object.keys(o1).filter(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty, o2);
}

console.log(intersection(firstObject, secondObject));
```

The same with previously bound `o2`.

```js
var firstObject = { x: 0, y: 1, z: 2, a: 10, b: 20, e: 30 },
    secondObject = { x: 0, y: 1, z: 2, a: 10, c: 20, d: 30 };

function intersection(o1, o2) {
    return Object.keys(o1).filter(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.bind(o2));
}

console.log(intersection(firstObject, secondObject));
```